# Affiliation with organization and its products/services in the response

Tags: discussion, policy, self-promotion, microsoft

I recently started on Stack Exchange, and have found myself in sort of a dilemma. When my answer is based on the technologies that are shipped by my employer (Microsoft), I am always in a quandary as to whether I should disclose my affiliation, and how much should I talk about those products/services. I do not want it to be perceived as marketing, as that is not what I intend to do (and it's not my job, nor am I rewarded for my contributions on SE.)

What are community guidelines, if any, for disclosing affiliations?

As an example, see the following responses from me:

- [OWA + AD Lockout Policy: Quite the Mixture](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61174/owa-ad-lockout-policy-quite-the-mixture/61184#61184): The question was pretty much about a Microsoft technology, and my response included a solution that Microsoft ships (and my current team is also using it).
- [How to safely store sensitive data like a social security number?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59580/how-to-safely-store-sensitive-data-like-a-social-security-number/61015#61015): My response includes both SQL server as well as MySQL, and it was a small part of the overall answer, so I ended up not saying who I work for explicitly.

Although both these questions are regarding security SE, I would like to know the general SE policy.
I personally do not want to disclose my affiliations, and it may also be considered distracting or even boastful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answers are valid solutions to the problems described in the questions, and not just links or advertisements. Further, looking at your other answers on the site I see you aren't just going around answering questions where you can advertise the company you work for.

So there's no reason to add a disclaimer to each post.  It'd be as annoying as any other signature, and those are disallowed on Stack Exchange.

If disclosure seems important to you, add something about your affiliation in [your user profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/47983/omer-iqbal).

Also, continue to answer any questions you can, whether your company has a solution for them or not.

Comment: Thanks Adam. This was helpful. I obviously would not add a disclaimer to "each post", but I was more concerned about the posts where I was talking about my company's products and/or services. Looks like your comment suggests that even in that case, I shouldn't feel the need to do so.